# R interactive plot: show vertical line on hover

Tags: r, interactive, rcharts, ggvis, googlevis

I have been looking around for a way to draw a vertical line along the x-axis when hovering over points in a plot using R. It does not really matter which package it is, whether it is plotly, ggvis, rCharts, googleVis or any other for that matter, but I would rather use one of the these mentioned ones if possible.

Here is an example of what I would like to have.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: this could be what you need https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/

Comment: Yes, I've been there, however I can't find the vertical line feature, is there one? Using any of rCharts, shiny or else would also include this hovering feature.

Comment: and what about this http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/nvd3-line-chart-output.html

Comment: I'll look into that, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A partial answer (can't comment)... Plotly has type "scattergl" which draws a horizontal and vertical line on hover.

**Data**

```
require(plotly)    

sdate <- as.Date("2015-01-01", format = "%Y-%m-%d")
timedf <- data.frame(Date = seq.Date(sdate, by="month", length.out=12),
                         Amount = runif(12, 0, 100))
# Plotly plot
plot_ly(timedf, x=Date, y=Amount, type="scattergl")
```

**Output**
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Follow Chris' answer, to make it work

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        column(width = 12,
               plotOutput("plot1", height = 350,hover = "plot_hover")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    testPlot <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg,y=disp,color=factor(cyl))) + 
        geom_point()

    #start up plot
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({testPlot})

    # plot after mouse over
    observeEvent(input$plot_hover, {
        x = input$plot_hover$x
        y = input$plot_hover$y
        nearPoint <- nearPoints(mtcars, input$plot_hover, 
                                threshold = 10, maxpoints = 1)
        output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
            if (nrow(nearPoint) == 1) {
                testPlot + 
                    geom_vline(xintercept = nearPoint$mpg) +
                    geom_label(x = x + 1.5, y = y, 
                               label = paste(rownames(nearPoint), "\n", nearPoint$disp))
            } else {
                testPlot
            }
        })
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a partial answer. I can't quite get it to work, but maybe someone will see something obvious. I've used `ggplot2` instead of `ggvis` for the `geom_vline()` function which creates a vertical line.

#### What's working:

On the `input$plot_hover` event, we assign the `x` coordinate to a variable (`h`) and then use that variable as the `xintercept` arguement to the `geom_vline()` function which draws a vertical line.

#### The problem:

Since this is happening in a reactive environment, on every update `h` is flushed, so the line disappears about a second after it first appears.

#### What I've tried:

I tried to assign `h` to a second variable `t` in order to keep it between updates. This didn't work, so I created a third variable `prev_t` and when there was no input (`is.null(input$plot_hover) == TRUE)`, keep `t` as `prev_t`. This also isn't working but I don't have a ton of time to try out different things.

Here's the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        column(width = 12,
               plotOutput("plot1", height = 350,hover = hoverOpts(id ="plot_hover"))
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
   #h <- reactive(input$plot_hover)

   prev_t <- vector()

    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

        if(!is.null(input$plot_hover)){
            x <- input$plot_hover
            h <- x$x
            t <- h


        # the below isnt quite working
        # I was trying to store t between updates to make the line stay on 
        # the graph until there was a second hover event

        ################### !!! ###################
        } else if(is.null(input$plot_hover)) {
            t <- prev_t
        }

        prev_t <- t
        ################## !!! ####################

        ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg,y=disp,color=factor(cyl))) + geom_point() + geom_vline(xintercept = t)

    })


}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Hopefully that should maybe put you on a different path or help a little. If someone sees something that could fix this problem, please let me know.

Comment: thank you! I'll experiment around with this and get back if I get it working!